# How to disable mouse wheel scrolling in GtkOptionMenu/GtkComboBox

Tags: c, gtk, scroll, mouse, mousewheel

Does anyone know how to disable mouse scrolling in a GtkOptionMenu or GtkComboBox? It is annoying when you are scrolling through a window and the pointer passed over such a widget which grabs the focus and changes value!

I see that the [offending code](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2001-September/msg00320.html) was added a while back, but there doesn't seem to be any mechanism in place to disable this functionality.

I am working in C, but help in any language would be much appreciated.

P.S. I should maybe mention that I'm using GTK 2.10, but need compatibility with GTK 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

This works - I hope might help someone else that wants to do the same thing:

```
/* Create new closure (callback) to replace class default */   
GClosure * new_closure = 
  g_cclosure_new_object( G_CALLBACK(handler), /* my event handler */
                         G_OBJECT(gobject) /* use any static GObject to keep closure alive */
                       );

GType type = gtk_option_menu_get_type();

/* Get signal_id for "scroll_event" */
guint signal_id = g_signal_lookup("scroll_event", type);

/* Override default closure for scroll_event signal */
g_signal_override_class_closure(signal_id, type, new_closure);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try disabling scroll events on the widget:

```
gtk_widget_set_events(GTK_WIDGET(box), gtk_widget_get_events(GTK_WIDGET(box)) & (GDK_ALL_EVENTS_MASK - GDK_SCROLL_MASK));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ptomato. Maybe this is to be expected, but gtk_widget_get_events always seems to return 0. I've tried setting events without ANDing (since that always gives 0 too) for the GtkOptionMenu and it's 'menu' and 'button' members to no avail :(

Comment: No, and gtk_widget_get_events() also returns 0.

Comment: Does help against scrolling a SpinButton, but unfortunately not with a ComboBox.

Comment: This works like a charm for GtkComboBox: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2016-May/msg00066.html